# Apache POI sumatory formula not giving desired result

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

in this code i want to get result and put it in java variable to use later but log show something else...

```
private void test() {
    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    try {
        //OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("Javatpoint.xls");
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("sheet");
        Cell cell1 = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);//A1
        Cell cell2 = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(1);//B1
        Cell cell3 = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(2);//C1
        Cell cell4 = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(3);//D1
        Cell cell5 = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(4);//E1

        cell1.setCellValue(5);//A1
        cell2.setCellValue(5);//B1
        cell3.setCellValue("A + ");//C1
        cell4.setCellValue("B is: ");//D1
        cell5.setCellFormula("A1+B1");//D1


        wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
        sheet.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);

        Log.i("loginf", String.valueOf(cell1.getNumericCellValue()));
        Log.i("loginf", String.valueOf(cell2.getNumericCellValue()));
        Log.i("loginf", cell3.getStringCellValue());
        Log.i("loginf", cell4.getStringCellValue());
        Log.i("loginf", "result: " + String.valueOf(cell5.getNumericCellValue()));

        //Log.i("loginf" , cell.getAddress().formatAsString());
        //wb.write(os);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("loginf", e.getCause().getMessage());
    }
}
```

result is:

```
    5.0
    5.0
    A +
    B is: 
    result: 0.0
    but A1+B1 should be 10 while is 0
```

Comment: Log.i("loginf", "result: " + String.valueOf(cell5.getNumericCellValue()));
Inside your log result,Where is result keyword?

Comment: As far as I can read you should first set the cell type ```cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);``` also I think that the formula isn't correct, try this one ```cell.setCellFormula("SUM(A1:B1)");```

Comment: Have you tried changing ```A1+B1``` for ```SUM(A1:B1)```?

Comment: A1+B1 and SUM(A1:B1) return equal result.

Comment: what is different of HSSFWorkbook with other simular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't create the row 5 times. Just change your cell initialization to the following to get the desired result:

```
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
Cell cell1 = row.createCell(0);//A1
Cell cell2 = row.createCell(1);//B1
Cell cell3 = row.createCell(2);//C1
Cell cell4 = row.createCell(3);//D1
Cell cell5 = row.createCell(4);//E1
```